# Openweathermaps parse json jquery forecast

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing, openweathermap

I'd like to display the weather forecast. so far i only managed to display one day.

HTML & Jquery code:  http://pastebin.com/cpZ0pE7G

The json is displayed in this format.

```
{
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0.0152,
   "city":{
      "id":524901,
      "name":"Moscow",
      "coord":{
         "lon":37.615555,
         "lat":55.75222
      },
      "country":"RU",
      "population":1000000
   },
   "cnt":4,
   "list":[
      {
         "dt":1375866000,
         "temp":{
            "day":26.19,
            "min":21.82,
            "max":26.19,
            "night":21.82,
            "eve":25.22,
            "morn":26.19
         },
         "pressure":1010.53,
         "humidity":77,
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":1.6,
         "deg":4,
         "clouds":24
      },
      {
         "dt":1375952400,
         "temp":{
            "day":24.92,
            "min":17.73,
            "max":25.32,
            "night":17.73,
            "eve":24.71,
            "morn":17.75
         },
         "pressure":1013.91,
         "humidity":71,
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":800,
               "main":"Clear",
               "description":"sky is clear",
               "icon":"01d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":1.61,
         "deg":20,
         "clouds":0
      },
      {
         "dt":1376038800,
         "temp":{
            "day":25.87,
            "min":16.74,
            "max":26.65,
            "night":22.17,
            "eve":26.42,
            "morn":16.74
         },
         "pressure":1011.31,
         "humidity":71,
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":800,
               "main":"Clear",
               "description":"sky is clear",
               "icon":"01d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":1.66,
         "deg":252,
         "clouds":0
      },
      {
         "dt":1376125200,
         "temp":{
            "day":22.72,
            "min":19.68,
            "max":25.42,
            "night":19.68,
            "eve":24.82,
            "morn":21.02
         },
         "pressure":1007.87,
         "humidity":73,
         "weather":[
            {
               "id":502,
               "main":"Rain",
               "description":"heavy intensity rain",
               "icon":"10d"
            }
         ],
         "speed":2.11,
         "deg":278,
         "clouds":80,
         "rain":15
      }
   ]
}
```

I only can parse the first line. How can i parse the other lines?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code here instead of (next to) a code dump on pastebin.

Comment: i managed to parse the pressure and humidity with: `weather.list.humidity`

Comment: but when i try the temp with: `weather.list.temp.day` i get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined `

Answer (score 0):

When you see brackets, it's an array, so you have to find the variable by the array key. `weather.list[0].temp.day` will return you 26.19. `weather.list[0].weather[0].main` will return you "Clouds" and `weather.list[1].weather[0].main` will return you "Clear".